# Is a String array a good structure to pass back a collection of values from a function?

Tags: .net, return-value

I have a function in an .NET application that operates on a collection of files and writes some files to disk. I want to return a collection of the filenames that have been written to disk. All I am going to do with the collection returned is to loop through each one and perform an operation on the file. I was initially thinking a String array would be best in this case but thought I might ask here in case another structure might serve better. For example would a `LIST<String>` be overkill if I am just looping through the collection? I am writing the function using VB.NET but C# examples are fine also. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If all you really need to be able to do is iterate over the results, it's sufficient to return an `IEnumerable<string>` from your function.**

This prevents coupling the caller to any particular data structure ... all they require is something can can be iterated. Your implementation is then free to use and return whatever structure makes sense - a `List<string>`, a `HashSet<string>`, a `string[]` ... it doesn't really matter. In fact, you are then free to create a datastructure other than a simple list if you so need - so long as it implements the `IEnumerable<string>` interface your callers are unaffected.

I think a different question to consider is whether an array is a good structure to internally use to build up a set of filenames. Is a fixed-size but mutable collection really the best construct for your operation? Often, such operations don't know how many items they will operate on - in which case a variable-sized collection (like `List<>` or `HashSet<>`) makes more sense. Why then incurr the cost of converting such a collection to an array simply to return it?

Comment: I really like what you had to say in your last paragraph. You make a good point that I may not have a fixed number of filenames. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Right out of Framework Design Guidelines - Icaza and Hejlsberg

8.1 "**Prefer** using collections to arrays for public APIs"

8.3.3 "**Prefer** collections over array"

BUT

"**Consider** using arrays in low level APIs to minimize memory consumption and maximize performance." (also part of 8.3.3)